# Is it possible logout terminal while running program

Tags: ssh, python, session

Say if I login using ssh, and run

> python a.py

For running the python program for some times.

Is it possible to logout the current session, while not stopping the python program, and be able to get back the current session while login again?

Comment: you could use screen for example (man screen for further explanation)

Comment: Use screen, nohup with the & , or start the program as a service.